# Android custom layout animation

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-intent, android-animation

all 
I have a tabbar in my Android app like pic

[image]

now I want to add a layout on the back of my tab bar like pic

[image]

and when I click the press button the layout appear with a flip animation to the top like pic

[image]

Help

Comment: You want flip animation or Translate from Bottom to top animation ?

Answer (score 1):

u can use frame layout in tab with bottom gravity. and on click you can adjust its size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) which already includes android sdk.

Here is simple tutorial : [link.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You should have to create One Layout let say pressLayout which contain that Press Button.

initially that layout is invisible. Now while you press on Tab or any other button, that Layout will show with the translate(or Scroll) animation from Bottom to Top.

Now while you click on Press Button. Set another animation on the Layout/view you want to effect.

Hope you got the point. For Translate Animation, you can see this: [translate Animation](http://blog.creatiosoft.com/?p=1042)

Enjoy coding...